# Правильно ли реализованно построение дерева Хаффмана?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Я пишу программу для сжатия данных на основе алгоритма Хаффмана. Реализовал класс, в котором строиться дерево Хаффмана но пока без присвоения 0 и 1 дугам дерева. Еще не разобрался, как это сделать. Перед этим я хочу узнать, правильно ли реализовано мной построения дерева Хаффмана?

```
class HaffmanTree 
        {
            private List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> tree;//список KeyValuePair, представляющий дерево. Где первый параметр типа символ, второй - его вес
            private List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> listOfFreeNodes;// список свободных узлов, где первый параметр типа это символ, а второй определяет свободен ли узел.
            private List<Node> treeNodes;// список, в котором храняться ссылки узла родителя на узлы потомки

            public HaffmanTree(char[] arraOfFrequency, int[] countOfFrequency)//первый параметр - символы, второй частота их повторени  
            {
                string[] strArrayOfFrequency = new string[arraOfFrequency.Length];//временный массив для символов
                for (int i = 0; i < strArrayOfFrequency.Length; i++)
                {
                    strArrayOfFrequency[i] = Convert.ToString(arraOfFrequency[i]);//заполняем данный массив
                }

                tree = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();//инициализируем дерево
                for (int i = 0; i < arraOfFrequency.Length; i++)
                {
                    tree.Insert(i, new KeyValuePair<string, int>(strArrayOfFrequency[i], countOfFrequency[i]));//заполняем дерево
                }

                listOfFreeNodes = new List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>();//инициализируем оставшиеся списки
                treeNodes = new List<Node>();
            }

            private void BuildListOfFreeNodes()//метод, для построения списка свободных узлов
            {
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> node in tree)
                {
                    listOfFreeNodes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(node.Key, true));
                }
            }

            private bool IsFreeElement(string key)//метод, который проверяет условие, не содержит узел потомок родительских узлов
            {
                return listOfFreeNodes.Any(node => key == node.Key && node.Value == true);
            }

            public void BuildTree()//метод для построения дерева хаффмана
            {
                IComparer<KeyValuePair<string, int>> comparer = new TreeCompare();
                KeyValuePair<string, int> left = default(KeyValuePair<string, int>);//инциализируем пустым значением ссылки на левого и правого потомка
                KeyValuePair<string, int> right = default(KeyValuePair<string, int>);
                tree.Sort(comparer);//сортируем дерево по частоте
                BuildListOfFreeNodes();//строим спискок свободных узлов.
                int countTrueValue = 0;

                while (countTrueValue != 1)//Пока не останется 1 свободный узел.
                {
                    int indMin1 = 0, indMin2 = 0;
                    int min1 = int.MaxValue, min2 = int.MaxValue;
                    string keyMin1 = string.Empty;
                    string keyMin2 = string.Empty;
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in tree.Where(kvp => kvp.Value < min1 && IsFreeElement(kvp.Key)))//Находим первый минимальный элемент
                    {
                        keyMin1 = kvp.Key;//запоминаем его ключ
                        indMin1 = tree.IndexOf(kvp);//запоминаем его индекс
                        min1 = kvp.Value;//запоминаем значение
                        listOfFreeNodes[indMin1] = new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(keyMin1, false);//убираем из списка свободных узлов
                        left = kvp;//присваиваем ссылку на первого потомка

                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp2 in tree.Where(kvp2 => kvp2.Value < min2 && (kvp2.Value == min1 || kvp2.Value > min1) && kvp2.Key != keyMin1 && IsFreeElement(kvp2.Key)))
                        {//находим второй минимальный элемент, производим аналогичные операции как и с первым минимальным элементом
                            indMin2 = tree.IndexOf(kvp2);
                            min2 = kvp2.Value;
                            keyMin2 = kvp2.Key;
                            right = kvp2;
                        }
                        listOfFreeNodes[indMin2] = new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(keyMin2, false);
                    }

                    string result = keyMin1 + keyMin2;//строка, которую будет содержать родительский узел
                    KeyValuePair<string, int> parentNode;//родительский узел
                    tree.Add(parentNode = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(result, min1
+ min2));//добавляем в дерево новый узел
                    treeNodes.Add(new Node(left, right, parentNode, min1 + min2));//создаем ссылки на новый узел
                    listOfFreeNodes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(result, true));//родительский узел становиться новым свободным узлом
                    countTrueValue = listOfFreeNodes.Count(kvp => kvp.Value
== true);//подсчитываем количество свободных узлов
                }
            }

            public void ShowHaffmanTree()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tree");
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> node in tree)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", node.Key, node.Value);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("List of free nodes");
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> node in listOfFreeNodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", node.Key, node.Value);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("List of treeNode");
                foreach(Node node in treeNodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(node.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

покажите результат сжатия и сразу будет видно соблюдены ли правила или нет.

хотя, когда я реализовывал подобное у меня дерево было "реальным" деревом, а не списком:

```
public class HuffmanNode
{
    private int _probability;
    private string _value;
    private HuffmanNode _leftNode;
    private HuffmanNode _rightNode;
    ...
}
```

- метод `ShowHaffmanTree()` лучше назвать просто `Show()`, а ещё лучше оставить логику представления дерева отдельно от его модели
- в конструктор передаёте `char[] arraOfFrequency`, потом перегоняете в `string[] strArrayOfFrequency`, почему бы не использовать что-то одно, избавитесь от лишнего цикла
- большинство комментариев отвечают на вопрос **"Что делаем?"**, но это и так ясно, лучше было бы, если бы они отвечали на впрос **"Зачем делаем?"**
- `...kvp2.Value > min1...` где `min1 = int.MaxValue;` условие избыточно, т.к. оно ВСЕГДА выполянется, если оно не выполняется вы получите ошибку намного раньше
- `(kvp2.Value == min1 || kvp2.Value > min1)` ещё раз посмотрите и подумайте, что вы написали=)

Comment: я не написал еще класс, который будет выполнять кодирование символов. Перед тем, как это делать, я хочу убедиться, соблюдена правильность построения дерева. Поэтому я не могу предоставить результаты сжатия. 
(kvp2.Value == min1 || kvp2.Value > min1) - Данное условие, написал для того, чтобы предусмотреть следующую ситуацию. Когда два имеются два минимальных значения, но при этом они могу быть равны друг другу или одно значение больше другого.

Comment: это смешно, существует же оператор `>=`, тем более, как я уже говорил `min1` у вас  - `int.MaxValue`! это условие просто бессмысленно, т.к. ни одно интовое значение не может быть больше этой константы

Comment: @Spectre и часто вы присваиваете переменной очень маленькое значение для нахождения минимума? (код не читал, некогда разбираться, просто коммент увидел)

Comment: @Spectre для поиска минимального значения переменной присваивается максимальное значение. Я даже специально воспользовался поиском на тему "поиск минимального элемента" и находил подобные решения. Во внешнем цикле находится первое минимальное значение, которое присваивается min1. Поэтому условие kvp2.Value > min1 выполниться.